# [Pushbullet Feature Suggestion]: Filter messages based on condition

Tags: pushbullet

Filter push notification based on condition (Regex etc..).

For example: messages contains specific string should not be displayed or should display the notification in private mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who ever interested in suggesting feature to PushBullet (PB).

You can find PB suggestion thread in the below reddit post:

https://www.reddit.com/r/PushBullet/comments/3zi8lp/janmar_suggestion_thread/